# Can you help me with my Database purging plan?

Tags: database, oracle

For the first time I'm trying to create a purge plan for a database.
What I want to do is: I have this database which keeps data about executed processes. To ensure that the database is in the best conditions and doesn't get slow, I want to implement a purge plan.

My plan is like this: I want that the Database, every 6 months, passes all the data that has been there for more than a year (I have audit fields for that) to another database, that would work as a warehouse of older data.. As for this warehouse database, I want that every 6 months eliminates all the data that is more than 5 years old.

However, I've been researching the net and I've been finding things like Purge VS Delete, Transporting Data, Migrations... And I still do not know what to do.
From what I understood, migration is about transporting data from different types of databases (Oracle <-> SQL Server for example). By the way, all these 3 databases I want to work with are Oracle (SQL Developer).
Should I define Stored Procedures for this? Sorry about the questions, but I really am a rookie at managing databases. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an Oracle stored procedure that selects all the data you wish to delete, insert that data to another database or write it to a file, and delete the data from your tables. I think Oracle PL/SQL is the most convenient, but I've also seen Java solutions for that. I don't know if you are proficient in one of those languages. I can help you with specific questions, but it's too much effort to provide you a complete solution.

Comment: I'm more used to PL/SQL than Java solutions... I will see what I can do. I was trying to solve this with PL/SQL anyway... If anything, I'll ask specific technical questions... Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your volumes are low or medium, any solution will work. Simple check in your test environment how long it takes to copy and delete 6 months of data. You will immediately (or later) see if simple insert / delete approach is suitable.

If not you may approach the delete (the more problematic) part twofold:

- partition your process table (range partitioning on the audit date)

The big advantage is that you need no delete, you use simple truncate partition.

The drawback is you will need a one time reorganization of the table and you must verify that the queries perfrom well (in theory, queries with audit time filter should *profit* from partitioning).

- reorganization of the table with leaving the older records out

A simple DIY way is to create a copy of the table containing only the new data.

```
CREATE TABLE process_new as 
SELECT * FROM process
WHERE audit_date >= <your limit>;
```

If you have an off-line maintainace window, simple replace the old table with the new one. Oracle provides more subtle variation on this concept with online redefinition - check [DBMS_REDEFINITION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_redefi.htm#CBBJJAIF)

The big advantage of this approach is that you realy release space (DELETE doesn't shrink the table, but leave holes in it), you may even reorder the records to optimize the access.

On the data warehouse part I'd definitively propose to define a partitioned table - [interval partition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm#insertedID2) on the audit time.

To copy the data, the simplest way is to insert them over a DB link.

General I'd suggest you should use the simplest way that meets your requirements.

Last but not least - check if your audit date is NULLABLE. If so and if there are some records with NULL audit date, remeber that they will never be moved, as NULL is never more than a year old...